# browser displaying old images when news ones are uploaded to the server (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a page that enables users to update images. But when the users perform the update the new images do not appear only the old ones. That's obviously a cache problem. I've tried some solutions like setting enableviewstate = false to the images and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this site. Add a query string to image url.

```
img2.ImageUrl = String.Concat(  "~/yourImage.jpg?" , rnd.Next()) ;
```